# Call Area controller action from main project view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC4 Project with some areas (i.e. PM, NOC etc). I have requirement when we click on link (anchor) of main project view, its redirect to area controller like PM/Testcontroller/testaction. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("action", "controller", new {area="***insert area of desired controller here***"})">link text</a>
```